# Powershell advanced regex to select from file

Tags: regex, file, select, powershell

I would like to search for a pattern in a file which I can do easily with something like:

```
gc $filename | select-string $pattern
```

However once I have found this first pattern, using the location (line) of the first match as a starting point I would then like to start searching for a second pattern. Once the second pattern has been matched I would then like to return all lines between the first and second matches, discarding the matched lines themselves.

Comment: can you provide an example of the input and the output you need?

Comment: A windows ini file is a close approximation to the type of file I am trying to parse

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your first pattern is pattern1 and the second pattern is pattern2

then expression would  be `(?<=pattern1)(.*?)(?=pattern2)`

`(?<=pattern1)` - this will match prefix pattern but exclude it from capture
`(?=pattern2)` - this will match suffix pattern but exclude it from capture

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more elegant way but this will work

```
function ParseFile
{
    param([string] $FileName)
    $s = gc $FileName;
    for($x = 0 ;   $X -lt $s.count; $x++)
    {
        if(-not $first ){ 
            if($s[$x] -match "1000"){
                $first =$x
            }
        } 
        else{
            if($s[$x] -match "1075"){
                $second = $x ; 
                break;
            } 
       }

    }
    (($first +1) .. ($second -1))|%{
        $ret += $s[$_]
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used `foreach` with `$foreach.Movenext()`:

```
foreach ($line in (Get-Content $file))
{
    if ($line -match $firstTag)
    {
        do {
            $line
            $foreach.MoveNext()
        } until ($foreach.current -match $secondTag)
        continue
    }
}
```

This will simply return each line one by one, but you can do what you like within the do-loop if you need to process the result in some way

Answer (score 1):

Here is my one (a french bricolage ;o) ), imagine the file c:\temp\gorille.txt :

```
C'est à travers de larges grilles,
Que les femelles du canton,
Contemplaient un puissant gorille,
Sans souci du qu'en-dira-t-on.
Avec impudeur, ces commères
Lorgnaient même un endroit précis
Que, rigoureusement ma mère
M'a défendu de nommer ici...
Gare au gorille !...
```

Here is the text between "canton" and "endroit"

```
PS > (((Get-Content -Path C:\temp\gorille.txt) -join "£" | Select-String -Pattern "(?=canton)(.*)(?<=endroit)").matches[0].groups[0].value) -split "£"
canton,
Contemplaient un puissant gorille,
Sans souci du qu'en-dira-t-on.
Avec impudeur, ces commères
Lorgnaient même un endroit
```

I join all the lines with a special character "£" (choose onather one if used) then use @Alex Aza pattern in CmdLet `Select-String` then split again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$start = select-string -Path $path -pattern $pattern1 -list |
  select -expand linenumber

$end = select-string -path $path -pattern $pattern2 |
  where-object {$_.linenumber -gt $start} |
  sort linenumber -desc |
  select -first 1 -expand linenumber

 (get-content $path)[$start..($end -2)]
```